# Answer edit as long and detailed comment from OP - how to proceed?

Tags: discussion

I wrote an answer to someones [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131817/authentication-error-at-login-after-online-upgrade-to-18-04) with the best intention to help. A few days later, I received an edit request for review:

[image]

Ignoring the fact, that this edit would completely destroy my answer, what would be the best way to preserve that feedback in askubuntu?

- Tell the guy to move it to the comment section? (seams to much and it would lose the context)
- Tell him to update and change his question? (that would change and double the size of his question)
- Something else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As this edit is OP’s reaction and feedback to your answer, it should be an edit to the question. There are three steps to take:

- Reject the edit as “Attempt to reply”
- Write a comment to OP asking them to update their question with the new information
  I did that now and shortened the citations to avoid unnecessarily redundant information.
- Edit your answer to account for the changed question

Comment: I was going to edit your answer with my comment "This is a great answer!" but I decided to post that here instead and upvote you :)

Answer (score 5):

I would accept it if it adds to the answer (but it does not ;) ). It is the person that asked the question so his -intent- is to add to your question what he thinks makes it a perfect answer.

He is adding things that are related to the question. So reject it and leave a comment